# Find conditional distribution and expectation if $(X,Y)$ is uniform on the unit square

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

${0<y<1}$, ${0<x<1}$

SUPPOSE f(x,y) = 1 given that, what is $E(X | X<Y)$?

SO FAR,what I got,

I draw (in the x-y plane) the region where f(x,y) is nonzero, then the region being conditioned on. So, the density must be 2x, for $0<x<1$ and 0 elsewhere.

$ f_{x|x<y} = \frac{f_{xy}}{f_{x<y}} = \frac{1}{1/x} = x, x \in [0,1]. $

I want to treat $(X|X<Y)$ itself as a random variable.

I'm stuck here, could please give a hint? or another way.(still don't get the point...)

Comment: Is $f$ the joint probability distribution?

Comment: @karmanaut actually,, there's no informotaion except the given..... so sorry,, that's why i'm so confused...

Comment: No conditional density is involved, you are asked to compute $E(X\mid X<Y)=E(X;X<Y)/P(X<Y)$. It should be clear that $P(X<Y)=\frac12$ and that $$E(X;X<Y)=\int_0^1x\int_x^1dydx=\ldots$$ "I want to treat (X|X<Y) itself as a random variable." This, one cannot do.

Comment: @A.S. No, $A=[X<Y]$ is an event and $E(X\mid A)=E(X\mathbf 1_A)/P(A)$ is **a number**. Please check the definitions.

Comment: @A.S. Hint: "$X<Y$" is not a random variable.

Comment: @Did Why can't we write Z as a RV such that Z = X if X < Y and Z = 0 otherwise? Aren't we translating an event into a RV?

Comment: @karmanaut One may define a new random variable $Z$ by $Z=X\mathbf 1_A$--but to do what? Sorry but "translating an event into a RV" is dangerously ambiguous. Please explain precisely what you mean by this.

Comment: We can now rewrite the expectation as $\int Pr(Z \geq z)dz$. Find the cdf is now easy to compute as outlined in Brian's answer. Does this sound correct to you?

Comment: @karmanaut 1. Yes, if $Z=X\mathbf 1_A$ then $\int_0^\infty P(Z\ge z)dz=E(Z)=E(X;A)$. 2. No, the answer below does not use $Z$. 3. Why report the job on finding the CDF of $Z$, as you said in the comment, as if it was simpler? 4. To produce ex nihilo the conditional CDF/PDF of $X$ conditionally on $X<Y$, as the answer below does, is not to solve the problem in the usual sense of "solve". 5. Please use @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region being conditioned on is the upper left half of the unit square, above the diagonal $y = x$.  There are different ways to the solution; one is to observe that $f_{X \mid X < Y}(x) = 2(1-x)$ and compute

$$
E(X \mid X < Y) = \int_{x=0}^1 xf_{X \mid X < Y}(x) \, dx
                = \int_{x=0}^1 2x(1-x) \, dx
                = \left. x^2-\frac{2x^3}{3} \right|_{x=0}^1 = \frac{1}{3}
$$

Another is to recognize that $F_{X \mid X < Y}(x) \equiv P(X < x \mid X < Y) = 2x-x^2$, and then

$$
E(X \mid X < Y) = \int_{x=0}^1 [1-F_{X \mid X < Y}(x)] \, dx
                = \int_{x=0}^1 (1-2x+x^2) \, dx
                = \left. x-x^2+\frac{x^3}{3} \right|_{x=0}^1 = \frac{1}{3}
$$

Another is to see that the centroid of the conditioned area lies at $(1/3, 2/3)$, so the average value of $X$ for that condition is $1/3$ (and the average value of $Y$ for that same condition is $2/3$).

ETA: Both Did and the OP have observed that this answer lacks a derivation of the conditional PDF. From the observation in the main post comment, above, we may obtain this PDF as

\begin{align}
f_{X \mid X<Y}(x)
   & = \frac{\int_{y=0}^1 f(x,y) \mathbb{1}_{x<y}\,dy}
            {\int_{z=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^1 f(z,y) \mathbb{1}_{z<y}\,dy\,dz} \\
   & = \frac{\int_{y=x}^1 f(x,y) \,dy}
            {\int_{z=0}^1 \int_{y=z}^1 f(z,y) \,dy\,dz} \\
   & = \frac{\int_{y=x}^1 \,dy}
            {\int_{z=0}^1 \int_{y=z}^1 \,dy\,dz} \\
   & = \frac{1-x}{\int_{z=0}^1 (1-z) \,dz} \\
   & = 2(1-x)
\end{align}

Comment: I'm not sure; those answers were removed.  But I suspect Did's objections were valid.

Comment: so given that you used the definition of the conditional expectation,,,it seems like your answer is correct, right? or is there another possibility here?

Comment: I don't think so (I mean, I don't think there are other possibilities).  Also, in the future, please spell out "you" and "your"; these answers and comments are preserved for posterity, and we like to maintain a modicum of professionalism here. :-)

Comment: thanks, how bout " 2(1-x)" why not 2x?

Comment: The interesting part of the exercise, that this answer omits, is to compute (not "to observe" or "to recognize") that $f_{X\mid X<Y}$ and/or $F_{X\mid X<Y}$ are what this answer says. (Ironically the OP chose to accept an answer based on this, but apparently has no clue why $f_{X\mid X<Y}$ and/or $F_{X\mid X<Y}$ are what this answer says they are.)

Comment: @Did: Hmm. It is missing, I will grant you that, but I find it no more interesting, inherently, than any other part of the problem. Since the distribution is uniform, I think it is straightforward to obtain the PDF from the geometry of the region over which the condition holds. In the interest of completeness, though, I agree it makes sense to add a discussion of that, so I shall.

Comment: Corrected several annoying typos in the edited part of the answer.